# Interesting System of Equations to solve.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I thought about this system of equations that I am interested in finding the solution to. I tried to solve it but wasn't able too since it isn't exactly easy to solve. I was wondering the best way to go about solving it without using brute force in a computer program. Is it even possible to come up with a good solution?

z has to be equal to naught, and it is not possible to use only integers.

$
\begin{cases}
z*e*r*o = 0 \\
o*n*e = 1 \\
t*w*o = 2 \\
t*h*r*e*e = 3 \\
f*o*u*r = 4 \\
f*i*v*e = 5 \\
s*i*x = 6 \\
s*e*v*e*n = 7 \\
e*i*g*h*t = 8 \\
n*i*n*e = 9 \\
t*e*n = 10 \\
\end{cases}
$

Comment: 1. $z = 0$ 
After what log it and get an system of linear  equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are eleven equations, but fifteen variables ($z$, $e$, $r$, $o$, $n$, $t$, $w$, $h$, $f$, $u$, $i$, $v$, $s$, $x$, and $g$). So there won't be a unique solution - at best, you could hope to find eleven of them in terms of the other four.

But taking the logarithm of each equation will make this doable: for example, $\ln{o * n * e} = \ln 1$ tells you that $\ln{o} + \ln{n} + \ln{e} = 0$. Then you can solve the system of linear equations for the logs of the variables; once you've done that, undo the logarithm to get the value of the variables.

Comment: Thanks this is a nice response

Answer (score 1):

The solutions can be expressed as
$$ \eqalign{f&={\frac {144\,{e}^{2}v}{5\,{r}^{2}{u}^{2}}},g={\frac {384\,{
v}^{2}{e}^{4}}{25\,r{u}^{2}}},h={\frac {54\,v}{25\,{r}^{2}u}},i={
\frac {25\,{r}^{2}{u}^{2}}{144\,{e}^{3}{v}^{2}}},n={\frac {36\,ev}{5\,
ru}},o={\frac {5\,ru}{36\,{e}^{2}v}},\cr s&={\frac {35\,ru}{36\,{e}^{3}{v}^
{2}}},t={\frac {25\,ru}{18\,{e}^{2}v}},w={\frac {1296\,{v}^{2}{e}^{4}
}{125\,{r}^{2}{u}^{2}}},x={\frac {31104\,{e}^{6}{v}^{4}}{875\,{r}^{3}{
u}^{3}}},z=0}
$$
with $e,r,u,v$ arbitrary nonzero numbers.